# jQuery click open/close div but need to close by clicking anywhere

Tags: jquery

Ok here is some jQuery code I'm using in order to click and open/close a div. It works great but I would like to be able to click anywhere on the page to close it. I read about e.stopPropagation but I don't know how I can use it in this code, or where to put it. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#test').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-menu" class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt="Menu" /></a>');
            $('a#toggle-menu').click(function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('#test').slideToggle(200);
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: You are returning false, no need then to use: `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-menu" class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt="Menu" /></a>');

    $('a#toggle-menu').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#test').slideToggle(200);
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('#test').length > 0 || $(e.target).closest('#toggle-menu').length > 0) return;
        $('#test').slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZJpT/)

Comment: Put my code inside the `$(document).ready()` function and after your code.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution without delegating event, this way you call event just when needed:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7mXJh/19)

just set attribute tabindex to the div and property CSS outline to 0.

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').on('blur', function (event) {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Using your code, set focus like that:

```
$('a#toggle-menu').click(function (e) {
    var $test = $('#test');
    $test.slideToggle(200,function(){if($test.is(':visible')) $test.focus();});        
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Demo works on lastest chrome stable version {37.0.2062.103 m}.

Comment: I am on 37.0.2062.94, and nothing happens.

Comment: Click anywhere on BODY except element itself. The DIV is hidden.

Comment: Haha, just figured it out. Sorry about that man. It does work! If you make an edit I'll up it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, what's wrong with this?

```
$('body').click( function() {
    $('#test').slideToggle( 200 );
});
```

Comment: You might consider using `.slideUp()` instead on body click, so it only closes (not opens) on click.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want clicking on the body to toggle the `div` **only if it's already open.**

Just use the following snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-menu" class="menu"><img src="images/menu.png" alt="Menu" /></a>');
    $('a#toggle-menu').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#test').slideToggle(200, function() {);
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $('body').on('click', function() {
                    $('#test').slideToggle(200);
                }
            }
            else {
                $('body').off('click');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This way, when the `div` is clicked, it waits for another click -- either anywhere on the `body` or on the `div` again -- to close the `div`. Once it's closed, only clicking on the `div` itself will open it again.